# In ArcGIS Pro, why are the colours of the polygons changing from a bright green to become greyed out as I zoom in?

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, topology, color

Recently imported map from ArcMap to Pro, all the symbology has been brought over correctly. When zoomed out, I can see all polygons with the correct colours. The polygons are a Red/Green and can be seen over imagery. I am editing the topology.

When I zoom in, the green colours become greyed out, and the red layer begins to look transparent, making it really difficult to see the edges of the polygons and thus edit them.

[image: imagery with polygon overlay, polygons shown are grey or transparent]

[image: imagery zoomed out, showing colours as they appear in the symbology layer]

**edits**
Versions: previously used ArcMap 10.8.1, now in ArcGIS Pro 2.0.8933 (as in control panel)

I believe the issue isn't to do with zoom at all now, it has the changes at all zoom levels, it only does this when going into edit the topology.

Comment: Maybe ArcPro is erroneously imposing some sort of scale display threshold? I would explore your layers symbology, as its impossible to answer this without at least seeing the layer symbology properties.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact releases of both products, e.g., ArcMap 10.8.1 and Pro 2.9.2.